# Как разделить 4 блока на 2 столбика?

Tags: html, css

```css
.section4 {
    background: #f5f5f5;
    height: 424px;
}

.reviews {
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #445161;
    padding: 30px 0 0 0;
}

.comment_bubble {
    margin: -75px 0 0 120px;
    width: 470px;
    height: 120px;
    background: #ebebeb;
    position: relative;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.comment_bubble:before {
    content: "";
    width: 2px;
    height: 0;
    right: 100%;
    top: 25px;
    position: absolute;
    border-top: 13px solid transparent;
    border-right: 15px solid #ebebeb;
    border-bottom: 13px solid transparent;
}

.userpic {
    height: 75px;
    width: 75px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #445161;
    margin: 0;
}

.comment {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-style: Italic;
    color: #333333;
    padding: 15px;
    margin: 0;
}

.author {
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #989898;
    margin: -5px 0 0 15px;
}

.indent {
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    margin-top: 30px;
}
```

```html
<section class="section4">
        <div class="container">
            
            <h2 class="reviews">
                Reviews
            </h2>

            <div class="indent">

                <div class="userpic">
                
                </div>

                <div class="comment_bubble">

                    <p class="comment">
                        Porro officia cumque sint deleniti nemo facere rem vitae odit inventore<br>cum odio, iste quia doloribus autem aperiam nulla ea neque<br> reprehenderit. Libero doloribus, possimus officiis sapiente<br> necessitatibus commodi consectetur?
                    </p>

                    <p class="author">
                        Lourens S.
                    </p>

                </div>

                </div>

                <div class="indent">

                <div class="userpic">
                
                </div>

                <div class="comment_bubble">

                    <p class="comment">
                        Porro officia cumque sint deleniti nemo facere rem vitae odit inventore<br>cum odio, iste quia doloribus autem aperiam nulla ea neque<br> reprehenderit. Libero doloribus, possimus officiis sapiente<br> necessitatibus commodi consectetur?
                    </p>

                    <p class="author">
                        Lourens S.
                    </p>

                </div>

                </div>

                <div class="indent">

                <div class="userpic">
                
                </div>

                <div class="comment_bubble">

                    <p class="comment">
                        Porro officia cumque sint deleniti nemo facere rem vitae odit inventore<br>cum odio, iste quia doloribus autem aperiam nulla ea neque<br> reprehenderit. Libero doloribus, possimus officiis sapiente<br> necessitatibus commodi consectetur?
                    </p>

                    <p class="author">
                        Lourens S.
                    </p>

                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="indent">

            <div class="userpic">
                
            </div>

            <div class="comment_bubble">

                <p class="comment">
                    Porro officia cumque sint deleniti nemo facere rem vitae odit inventore<br>cum odio, iste quia doloribus autem aperiam nulla ea neque<br> reprehenderit. Libero doloribus, possimus officiis sapiente<br> necessitatibus commodi consectetur?
                </p>

                <p class="author">
                    Lourens S.
                </p>

            </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </section>
```

Answer (score 1):

Вот тебе один из вариантов:

```css
.section4 {
  background: #f5f5f5;
  display: table;
}

.reviews {
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #445161;
  padding: 30px 0 0 0;
}

.comment_bubble {
  margin: -75px 0 0 120px;
  background: #ebebeb;
  position: relative;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.comment_bubble:before {
  content: "";
  width: 2px;
  height: 0;
  right: 100%;
  top: 25px;
  position: absolute;
  border-top: 13px solid transparent;
  border-right: 15px solid #ebebeb;
  border-bottom: 13px solid transparent;
}

.userpic {
  height: 75px;
  width: 75px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #445161;
  margin: 0;
}

.comment {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-style: Italic;
  color: #333333;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 0;
}

.author {
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #989898;
  margin: -5px 0 0 15px;
}

.indent {
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<section class="section4">
  <div class="container">

    <h2 class="reviews">
      Reviews
    </h2>

    <div class="indent">

      <div class="userpic">

      </div>

      <div class="comment_bubble">

        <p class="comment">
          Porro officia cumque sint deleniti nemo facere rem vitae odit inventore<br>cum odio, iste quia doloribus autem aperiam nulla ea neque<br> reprehenderit. Libero doloribus, possimus officiis sapiente<br> necessitatibus commodi consectetur?
        </p>

        <p class="author">
          Lourens S.
        </p>

      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="indent">

      <div class="userpic">

      </div>

      <div class="comment_bubble">

        <p class="comment">
          Porro officia cumque sint deleniti nemo facere rem vitae odit inventore<br>cum odio, iste quia doloribus autem aperiam nulla ea neque<br> reprehenderit. Libero doloribus, possimus officiis sapiente<br> necessitatibus commodi consectetur?
        </p>

        <p class="author">
          Lourens S.
        </p>

      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="indent">

      <div class="userpic">

      </div>

      <div class="comment_bubble">

        <p class="comment">
          Porro officia cumque sint deleniti nemo facere rem vitae odit inventore<br>cum odio, iste quia doloribus autem aperiam nulla ea neque<br> reprehenderit. Libero doloribus, possimus officiis sapiente<br> necessitatibus commodi consectetur?
        </p>

        <p class="author">
          Lourens S.
        </p>

      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="indent">

      <div class="userpic">

      </div>

      <div class="comment_bubble">

        <p class="comment">
          Porro officia cumque sint deleniti nemo facere rem vitae odit inventore<br>cum odio, iste quia doloribus autem aperiam nulla ea neque<br> reprehenderit. Libero doloribus, possimus officiis sapiente<br> necessitatibus commodi consectetur?
        </p>

        <p class="author">
          Lourens S.
        </p>

      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Какая то жесть получается. Фон ограничен, столбцы прилегают друг к другу

Comment: Сделал короче через columns, вроде получилось

Comment: @Max Maximum я же не буду за тебя всё делать. в том варианте, можно отредактировать так, что всё нормально будет.

Comment: через колумн может быть такое: http://prntscr.com/t5kcqc

Comment: так и было. Я сгруппировал их по 2 и разделил на колонки. Просто, я получаю ответы, но не знаю некоторых тегов и как они действуют, поэтому и говорю, как есть. Все равно, спасибо